# xcode 7.3.1, linker command failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, linker-errors

Already asked a question about this but I still have the issue and need more help. What does this mean?(null): File not found: /Users/josephcatley/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Catley_Lakeman_Securities_-bgmbarzibqvxrrcfnrptvxmzywgr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CLS.app/CLS

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your Derived Data:
Window > Projects > click 'Delete' where it says 'Derived Data'

This usually works for me.